# Python variable value adding a double quotes

Tags: python

input_file.txt has below

```
'123','345','567'|001
'1234','3456','5678'|0011
```

below is the code I am using to assign the values from input_file.txt to v_order_nbr_lst, which is working fine , but when I am using that variable inside a POST message API call like below , it is adding double quotes.

## read the input file

```
fileHandle = open(input_file.txt,'r')

for line in fileHandle.readlines()[0:]:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    fields = line.split('|')
    v_order_nbr_lst = (fields[0])
```

## variable used below

```
postdata = {
    "parameters": [
        {
        "Order_Nbr": [v_order_nbr_lst]
             }
          ]
     }
```

Now I am getting values with double quotes like this , i tried to replace & rstrip but not able to get rid of ".

```
postdata = {
    "parameters": [
        {
        "Order_Nbr": ["'123','345','567'"]
             }
          ]
     }
```

**expected result**

```
postdata = {
    "parameters": [
        {
        "Order_Nbr": ['123','345','567']
             }
          ]
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `v_order_nbr_lst` is not what you think, look:

```
line = "'123','345','567'|001"
fields = line.split('|')
v_order_nbr_lst = fields[0]

v_order_nbr_lst
=> "'123','345','567'" # this is a string, not a list!
```

Try this instead:

```
v_order_nbr_lst = fields[0].replace("'", '').split(',')
```

And assign the value like this:

```
"Order_Nbr": v_order_nbr_lst
```

Comment: Your solution works , but I had to remove [ ] in post data as  v_order_nbr_lst adds [ ]                                                     
                                                                                       
 v_order_nbr_lst = fields[0].replace("'", '').split(',')                       
                                                                                                  
 postdata = {
    "parameters": [
        {
        "Order_Nbr": v_order_nbr_lst
             }
          ]
     }

Comment: Er, that's what the last line says: remove the `[]`